# Django prefetch_related with ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

I have this two models im my django application (latest version).

```py
class Focal(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(....)

class Company(models.Model):
        trade_name = models.CharField(....)
        focal = models.ManyToManyField(Focal)
```

Django automaticaly created a third table to conect the models: `company_focal`.

I want to implement the `prefetch_related` in the Focal Admin queryset.

I
I've been trying something like this, but it didnt worked well.

```
@admin.register(Focal)
class FocalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(FocalAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return queryset.prefetch_related('company')
```

The idea to insert all companies that the focal is connected using inline at admin. The inline isn`t the problem, the massive use of database is.

How to correctly do it?

Answer (score 1):

prefetch_related is applied on a many to many field. In your case this should be to the Company model, something similar to:

```
Company.objects.prefetch_related('focal')
```

[Check this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) for more information on the matter.

Comment: When i'm on **Company** Admin queryset, i can use the `select_related("focal")` and its fine.

But when i`m on **Focal Admin** queryset this `prefetch_related("focal")` dont work.

I`ll edit the question to express it too

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

```py
return queryset.prefetch_related('company_set')
```